# How to write json using NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nlog

My main goal is to write and then read the following information using NLog. I have done the following but not able to move forward with this,

NLOG config,

```xml
  <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog" layout="${message}" log="Application" source="My App" />
      <target name='jsonFile' type='File' fileName='${basedir}/APILog/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-webapi.json'>
        <layout type='JsonLayout'>
          <attribute name='time' layout='${longdate}' />
          <attribute name='executedby' layout='${executedby}' />
          <attribute name='username' layout='${username}' />
          <attribute name='deletedFromDB' layout='${deletedFromDB}' />
          <attribute name='deletedFromAD' layout='${deletedFromAD}' />
        </layout>
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="eventlog" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="jsonFile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

This is what I would like to read and write to this file,

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string ExecutedBy { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string deletedFromDB { get; set; }
    public string deletedFromAD { get; set; }
}
```

Code

> var entryJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry);
>
> // LOOKS LIKE THIS
>
> "{\"Time\":\"2018-03-02T11:33:55.426732+00:00\",\"ExecutedBy\":\"REMOVED\",\"Username\":\"exampleusername\",\"ExistingQAFromDB\":\"0\",\"ExistingQAFromAD\":\"False\",\"DeletedFromDB\":\"True\",\"DeletedFromAD\":\"false\",\"Status\":null}";
>
> _logger.Debug(entryJson);

And outcome is...

> { "Time": "2018-03-02 11:34:01.1948" }

How can I read and write this LogEntry object to the log file ?

Comment: @Liam even if I enter correct formatted json, it's not going into file, all I am getting is time as I suspected :(

Comment: _logger.Debug("JSON Debug Message"); - you are creating a logentry without any data. NLog has nothing to substitute your custom tokens with (${username}, ${executedby}" and other.

Comment: @n.piskunov even if input is like this,          _logger.Debug(@"{'time': '2018-03-02 11:19:50.4983','executedby': 'executedby'}");... I get  back { "time": "2018-03-02 11:23:06.2556" }

Comment: I added full object now

Comment: No, inspect the signature of Debug() method you are using. Passing a single string argument - means passing a message. And you haven't specified message output in your NLog template entry. The tokens in NLog layout are predefined. If you want to render your json-obj props as NLog layout tokens - you need to write custom layout renderer, The easier alternative is to use event Properties. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout

Comment: @n.piskunov I get you, I will have to use NLog template, I can add custom properties to message part and then read them later on

Answer (score 1):

You are already writing pure JSON to NLog. No need to also activate the NLog JsonLayout.

Just do this:

```
  <target name='jsonFile' type='File' fileName='${basedir}/APILog/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-webapi.json' layout='${message}' />
```